# Dynamic questionnaire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a questionnaire using ASP.Net and C#
it's a list of questions and based on each answer another question appears (e.g. Is this X or Y? if you choose X from the radio button list you'll get another question "what's the color of x" and if you choose Y "hos fast is Y")

what i made so far is that i made about 7 labels with radiobutton lists (number of questions) , set them to invisible, and based on the first question's answer i make the second label and radio button list visible, and change the text to the question i want.

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //first question
{
    //selected value =0 => No || selected value= 1 => Yes
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Question number 2 based on answer a"; //show the second question
        RadioButtonList2.Visible = true; //show the second question options

    }
    else {
        Label1.Text = "Question number 2 based on answer b";
        Label1.Visible = true; //show the second question
        RadioButtonList2.Visible = true; //show the second question options
    }
}

protected void RadioButtonList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //2nd question
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1" && RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "1") //1st question answer was yes &2nd is yes
    {
        //some logic here
    }
```

it's working fine till now with this logic, but is there's a more neat logic than this ?
and after answering question number 7 for example and then i made a modification in question number 4, how can i make the answered questiones (5,6,7) cleared and hidden again?!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't provide code about this, but is a possible idea that you may find useful.

From your description one data structure came to my mind. `Tree`. It looks like your problem can be implemented using Object Oriented programming by implementing your questions into a `Tree` data structure.

Each node in the Tree can have a unique identifier (i.e ID) this will make possible to link your radio-buttons with the Tree.

If we have question `A` and question `B`, and `B` is depending on the question `A`, then `B` question will be child of `A` question.

So you could then depending on the user's option to traverse the Tree by marking each visited node as `Visited` this will help you to keep track of the "path" that the user currently is following.

Here is a possible (draft) structure of your Tree node:

```
internal class Node
{
   private int ID { get; private set; }
   private string NodeQuestion { public get; public set; }
   private int State { public get; public set; } // 0 for Non-Visited, 1 for Visited
   private Node Left { public get; public set; }
   private Node Right { public get; public set; }

   public Node(...)
   {
     ....
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: you're right !, That's a brilliant idea, I'm working on it right now

Comment: I am glad that I help